# PowerPoint retrieve slide data

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

I am trying to get the PowerPoint Slide content as byte[] or as base64, but support for this scenario in the documentation or library code is missing.

In the current implementation, I am downloading the full PowerPoint as in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint), but it is only a temporary solution.

Does anyone know if this scenario is supported or a workaround exists?

*PowerPointApi 1.2*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not supported at this time. I encourage you to suggest is at: [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/search.html?c=&includeChildren=&f=&type=question%20OR%20idea%20OR%20kbentry%20OR%20answer%20OR%20topic%20OR%20user&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=office-js-dev).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
Do you know any workaround that can help me achieve this?

Comment: There is a way to get slides from one presentation and and insert them into the current presentation, but it does not give them to you as a byte array or base64.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? Maybe that could help. Thanks!

Comment: Install the [Script Lab tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) in PowerPoint and you will find an example in it.